# WCF - Stress Test - Slow Perfomance

Tags: performance, wcf, iis-7, .net-4.0, dynatrace

We had a problem with our WCF endpoint performance, so we did a stress test to get more information regarding this.

**Our environment:**

- LOAD BALANCER;
- 4 HOSTS(4vCPUS and 4Gb RAM) each;

**Application Configuration**

- CPU Limit Application Pool: 0 (default – NO LIMIT)
- Threads Per Processor Limit: 25 (default)
- ASP Queue Length property: 3000
- MaxPoolThreads registry entry:  Not Set
- Connection TImeout: 120 seconds (2 minutes)

**STRESS TEST DATA**
 - 5000 Requests in 10 minutes

**STRESS TEST RESULT**
The tests results were observed using Dynatrace.
 - Initially we have a response time of 24,6(which is too much time)
 - As soon more requests were received, more our response time increased. Reaching up to 55,3 minutes.
 [image: Dynatrace Data]
 [image: Dynatrace Data]
 [image: Dynatrace Data]

**WCF CONFIGURATIONS**

- Result Object:

  [image: Object]
- WebConfig Segments configurations:
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: What is your normal/fastest execution time of a request? So a single request is already taking 24,6 seconds even if there is no other user sending any requests? Or is it so high, because the services are not warmed up for the first request?

Comment: Hi @Marc, we did an stress test with our client last week again, and the avarage response time is about 24,6 seconds. Locally, debuging code, each request has  a very different response time, some of them around 200 milliseconds, some about 9 seconds.

Comment: One thing that I'm trying to do now is to create a virtual directory in IIS, in order to improve the windows authentication time. I hope that with the virtual directory IIS authenticate just one time.

Comment: I was taking a look around the web too, and got some ideas regarding throttling and cache(which i don't know if is applicable to my scenario, I mean, each request return different data/document)